# Nonsingular 2-form of a manifold of odd dimension and its null curve

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

$M$ : differentiable manifold 
$\omega$ : 2-form of $M$ 
2-form $\omega$ is defined to be **nonsingular** if dim$(\mathrm{Ker}\omega_x^{\flat})=1$ at any point $x \in M$, where$\omega^{\flat}_x : T_x M \rightarrow T^*_xM, v \mapsto \omega^{\flat}_x(v):= \omega_x(v,\cdot)$.
When the tangent vector $\dot{c}(t):=c_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})$ of a smooth curve $c : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow M, t \mapsto c(t)$ satisfies $\dot{c}( t) \neq 0$ and $\omega^{\flat}_{c(t)}(\dot{c}(t))=0$ in any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we call $c$ a **null curve** in $\omega$.

My textbook said that if $M$ is an odd dimensional manifold and a 2-form $\omega$ of $M$ is nonsingular, then for any point in $M$ there exists a unique null curve of $\omega$ through that point, but the proof was omitted. Could you please tell me this proof or let me know the book in which the proof is written?

Comment: did you mean $\dot c(t) \neq 0$?

Comment: I apologise you are correct. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is true is that through for any $p \in M$ and $v \in \ker \omega_p$, there exists a unique curve $c\colon \Bbb R \to M$, **up-to parametrization**, such that $c(0) = p$, $\dot c(0) = v$ and $\dot c(t) \in \ker \omega_{c(t)}$ for all $t$.
The proof, in short, is the following: $\ker \omega$ is an integrable regular distribution.
Let me expand on this.

$\newcommand{\D}{\mathcal{D}} \newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{d}}$
Let $\D = \ker \omega \subset TM$, which is by assumption a rank $1$ tangent distribution.
It is a classical thing that a rank $1$ distribution is always integrable.
Here is a proof that is specific to this example.
Fix $X$ and $Y$ two vector fields tangent to $\D$.
Let $Z$ any third vector field and $\alpha$ be the $1$-form defined as $\alpha(V) = \omega(V,Z)$.
Since $\D$ has rank $1$, $X$ and $Y$ are pointwise colinear, so that $\dx\alpha(X,Y) = 0$.
Hence
\begin{align}
0
&= \dx\alpha(X,Y) \\
&= X(\alpha(Y)) - Y(\alpha(X)) - \alpha([X,Y])\\
&= X(\omega(X,Z)) - Y(\omega(Y,Z)) - \omega([X,Y],Z)\\
&= -\omega([X,Y],Z).
\end{align}
Hence, $\omega([X,Y],Z) = 0$ for any $Z$.
It follows that $[X,Y]$ is tangent to $\D$.
One then concludes thanks to Frobenius theorem: $M$ is foliated by the integral submanifolds of $\D$, which are precisely unparametrized null-curves of $\omega$.

Comment: I really appreciate you.